# How to change the font of paragraph titles in memoir?

Tags: memoir

I'm using the memoir class with the "veelo" chapter style and would like to display the title of a paragraph in italics rather than boldface.

```
\paragraph{This should be displayed in italics}
```

I found `\chaptitlefont` but nothing similar for paragraphs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The font for a `\paragraph` title can be changed with `\setparaheadstyle`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\setparaheadstyle{\itshape} % memoir manual, section 6.6

\begin{document}

\paragraph{This should be in italics}
And this shouldn't.

\end{document}
```

[image]